# How can I override all Insurgency/Source game mode settings?

Tags: server-administration, source-engine, insurgency

I want to apply some Insurgency configuration to all game modes. For example, `mp_supply_token_bot_base 20` for Checkpoint, Occupy, and all other modes.

It seems like the [Source engine configuration files](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/CFG) get executed in this order:

1. `server.cfg`
2. `default_server_{gamemode}`
3. `server_{gamemode}` (if it exists)

So, I can't just put things in `server.cfg`, because the default game mode files will override them. I can manually create a file for every game mode, but that's tedious. Is there a better way?

Ideally I'm looking for a `.cfg` file that runs very late, after all other config files (including `default_server_{gamemode}` have run. That way I can override all the `default_server_{gamemode}` files with just one file.